# Loading offsets and metadata blocks KafkaConsumer after broker restart for a long time

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

we have the problem that sometimes calls to the 'poll' method of the new KafkaConsumer hangs for as long as ***20 to 30 Minutes*** after one out of three kafka brokers got restartet !

We are using a 3 broker kafka setup (0.9.0.1). 
Our Consumer-Processes use the new Java KafkaConsumer-API and we are
assigning to specific TopicPartitions.

for different reasons i can't show the real code here, but basically our code works like this :

```
Properties consumerProps=loadConsumerProperties();
// bootstrap.servers=<IP1>:9092,<IP2>:9092,<IP3>:9092
// group.id="consumer_group_gwbc2
// enable.auto.commit=false
// auto.offset.reset=latest
// session.timeout.ms=30000
// key.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
// value.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer

KafkaConsumer<String, byte[]> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(consumerProps);
consumer.assign(Arrays.asList(new TopicPartition("someTopic",0)));

while (true) {

  // THIS CALL sometimes blocks for a very long Time after a broker restart
  ConsumerRecords<String, byte[]> records = kafkaConsumer.poll(200);

  Iterator<ConsumerRecord<String, byte[]>> recordIter = records.iterator();
  while (recordIter.hasNext()) {                
     ConsumerRecord<String, byte[]> record = recordIter.next();

     // Very fast, actually just sending a UDP Paket via Netty.
     processRecord(record); 

     if (lastCommitHappendFiveOrMoreSecondsAgo()) {   
       kafkaConsumer.commitAsync();
     }
  }
}
```

kafka-topics.sh describes the ***__consumer_offsets*** topic as follows

```
Topic:__consumer_offsets    PartitionCount:50   
ReplicationFactor:3 Configs:segment.bytes=104857600,
cleanup.policy=compact,compression.type=uncompressed
```

the server.log of the restarted broker shows that loading the offsets from a specific partition of the __consumer_offsets topic takes a long time (in this case about 22 Minutes). This correlates to the time the 'poll' call of the consumer is blocked.

```
[2016-07-25 16:02:40,846] INFO [Group Metadata Manager on Broker 1]: Loading offsets and group metadata from [__consumer_offsets,15] (kafka.coordinator.GroupMetadataManager)
[2016-07-25 16:25:36,697] INFO [Group Metadata Manager on Broker 1]: Finished loading offsets from [__consumer_offsets,15] in 1375851 milliseconds.
```

i'am wondering what makes the loading process so slow and what can be done about it !?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the reason.

the server.xml configuration files for our brokers contain the property

```
log.cleaner.enable=false
```

(by default this property is true as of version 0.9.0.1)
this means that kafkas internal compacted ***__consumer_offsets*** topic
is not actually compacted since the log-cleaner is disabled.
in effect some partitions of this topic grew to a size of serveral gigabytes which explains the amount of time needed to read through all of the consumer-offsets data when a new group-coordinator needs to refill it's cache.

Comment: You may experience similar issues in version 2.0 2.1 and 2.2 due to following bug in Kafka: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-8335